# R Transform Data Frame and Remove NAs

Tags: r, transform, na

I've converted a data set in R from LONG to WIDE format and now have one measurement per row. What would be the best way to consolidate the rows based on the "Date" column and remove the NAs?

Here is a sample of what I have:

```
    Date    M1  M2  M3  M4
1   2013    NA  NA  NA  2
2   2013    6   NA  NA  NA
3   2013    NA  19  NA  NA
4   2013    NA  NA  10  NA
5   2014    NA  NA  NA  1
6   2014    NA  NA  231 NA
7   2014    NA  215 NA  NA
8   2014    16  NA  NA  NA
```

This is what I'd like to create:

```
    Date    M1  M2  M3  M4
1   2013    6   19  10  2
2   2014    16  215 231 1
```

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you go back to where you started to make the data wide? It might be better to address the problem at the source.

Comment: I used tidyr package spread() function on the long data format. I basically did this: df2 <- spread(df1, Measurements, Total).

Comment: @bridgbro You may need to show the original example i.e. `df1`  If I try to recreate the long form from the example showed, `dfN <- gather(df1, Var, Val, -Date) %>% na.omit(); spread(dfN, Var, Val)` gives the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing more about your dataset, you can try something like this:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = Date]
#    Date M1  M2  M3 M4
# 1: 2013  6  19  10  2
# 2: 2014 16 215 231  1
```

It doesn't have to be using "data.table" (but that's going to be one of your fastest options) but can be any one of your favorite aggregation functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you have one measurement per row:

```
result<-aggregate(cbind(M1=data$M1, M2=data$M2, M3=data$M3, M4=data$M4), 
                  by=list(Date= data$Date), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

**Edit**
This is better as mentioned by Ananda in the comments:

```
 aggregate(. ~ Date, mydf, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = "na.pass")
```

Comment: Or, more generally, `aggregate(. ~ Date, mydf, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = "na.pass")`.

Comment: What does  `na.action = "na.pass"` do?

Comment: The formula method for `aggregate` deals with `NA` values differently from the basic method. This is kind of like saying keep the `NA` values for consideration (which we override with `na.rm` from `sum`).

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1%>% 
   group_by(Date) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))
#  Date M1  M2  M3 M4
#1 2013  6  19  10  2
#2 2014 16 215 231  1
```

If there is only one non-NA observation per each column per 'Date', you could replace the `summarise_each` step with `summarise_each(funs(na.omit(.)))`